# How to prefill a form field using POST method data?

Tags: javascript, forms, post, input

Im trying to figure out how to prefill a form field with a value from the previous page.

The form on the first page uses post method.

Need the right script that will take a value from the previous page and fill it in a form field thats input has only a name and not an ID.

I cant change, modify, or assign ids to any inputs becuase I dont have access to much of the code.  Can add code, but hardly modify or change exsisting.  This is for a online shop's cart that is limited in functionality and so I am just trying to add some incase your wondering.  Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks to all.

Comment: It depends on the server-side language being used.

Comment: please post some code so can start helping you.

Comment: posted code for form on 1st page

Answer (score 0):

From what you are saying ...  You need to be able to change a inputs value based on "name":

```
<script>
$('input[name=YourFieldName]').attr(
    {value: 'YOUR POST DATA'});
});
</script>
```

You will also need to use ASP to get the POST data ...  If you are able to use ASP it would look something like

```
<%
Dim TEXTBOX_A
TEXTBOX_A = Request.Form("TEXTBOX_A")
%>

<script>
$('input[name=TEXTBOX_A]').attr(
    {value: '<% Response.Write(TEXTBOX_A) %>'});
});
</script>
```

If I have misunderstood, please correct me.

Comment: what do i put where it says 'YOUR POST DATA'

Comment: dont have access to asp...could I use Javascript for this?

Comment: No ..  JavaScript does not have direct access to POST data.  I know it's inconvenient, but JavaScript is purely "client side" and cannot (mainly for security reasons) access "server side" data